# I see "-->" on the top of page in Blogger template?

Tags: html, xml, blogger

Hello People Good day to all..

I was trying some stuff..

Made a blog, inserted a "blank html static template" , code is below.

but on the top of i i am seeing "-->" and I'm unable to remove it please tell me what to do?? how can i

Here is the code

http://pastebin.com/28zqfgut

this is the blog link where tempalte it applied: http://goo.gl/Se4f34

Comment: Why when people cant help here someone they just come and down vote? I have tried my best to remove it tried html codes etc. but its not getting right... please make it clear to me anyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change this

```
<style id='page-skin-1' type='text/css'><!--
  #navbar-iframe {   height:0px;   visibility:hidden;   display:none   }
  body {
  font: $(body.font);
  color: $(body.text.color);
  background: $(body.background);
  padding: 0 $(content.shadow.spread) $(content.shadow.spread) $(content.shadow.spread);
  $(body.background.override)  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  }
  <style type="text/css">
  html {overflow: auto;}
  html, body, div, iframe {margin: 0px; padding: 0px; height: 100%; border: none;}
  iframe {display: block; width: 100%; border: none; overflow-y: auto; overflow-x:             hidden;}
  </style>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://onlinehtmltools.com/tab-generator/skins/skin5/top.css"></script>

--></style>
```

into this

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://onlinehtmltools.com/tab-generator/skins/skin5/top.css">

<!-- <style id='page-skin-1' type='text/css'>
  #navbar-iframe { 
    height:0px;
    visibility:hidden;
    display:none
  }
  html {overflow: auto;}
  html, body, div, iframe {margin: 0px; padding: 0px; height: 100%; border: none;}
  body {
  font: $(body.font);
  color: $(body.text.color);
  background: $(body.background);
  padding: 0 $(content.shadow.spread) $(content.shadow.spread) $(content.shadow.spread);
  $(body.background.override)  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  }
  iframe {display: block; width: 100%; border: none; overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: hidden;}

</style> -->
```

and if you want, you can also comment the `top.css`

```
<!-- <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://onlinehtmltools.com/tab-generator/skins/skin5/top.css"> -->
```